# QueryPerformanceFrequency and QueryPerformanceCounter for Linux

Tags: c++, linux, windows, winapi, posix

I am trying to write a equivalent in Linux to this function in Windows:

```
double CputimeInUsecs()
    {
        double RetCputime = 0;
        LARGE_INTEGER   performanceCounter = {};
        LARGE_INTEGER   performanceFrequency = {};
            QueryPerformanceFrequency(&performanceFrequency);
            GEN_IGNORE(QueryPerformanceCounter(&performanceCounter));
        RetCputime = static_cast<double>(performanceCounter.QuadPart) / (static_cast<double>(performanceFrequency.QuadPart) / 1000000.0);
        return RetCputime;
    }
```

I read at some places that clock_gettime when passed with CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID might solve the issue , but I am not sure about it. What is the possible implementation of this in Linux?

Comment: Use [`std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock).